# Putty suddenly stops drawing lines with fixedsys

Tags: windows-7, fonts, putty

I have Putty configured to use Fixedsys font which looks great. Sometimes however putty stops drawing lines (like in mc or ncurses apps) for no apparent reason. All line drawing characters are replaced by empty rectangles.

Problem persists even if I kill all putty instances, pageant and other programs. Strangely, everything is back to normal after system restart.

What could be the cause of this weird behaviour ?